# How do you pass an ID to a function that will use that ID to query data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So to start, this is my table which shows the students data:

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>Name(Lastname, Firstname)</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Modify</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="student in students.data" :key="student.student_id">
            <td>{{student.student_id}}</td>
            <td>{{student.lastname | upFirstLetter}}, {{student.firstname | upFirstLetter}} </td>
            <td>{{student.contact_no}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal" @click="loadStudentData(student.student_id)">
                    <i class="fas fa-eye text-teal"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When the view icon is clicked it calls and passes the student_id to a function named **loadStudentData()**

```
loadStudentData(id) {
    this.form.show('api/loadData' + id).then(({data}) => (this.studentsData = data));
}
```

and for the `function show($id)` inside the controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Students::orderBy('student_id', 'asc')
        ->join('student_details', 'student_details.student_id', 'students.student_id')
        ->where('students.student_id', '=', $id)
        ->select('students.*', 'student_details.*');
}
```

This is what I've tried so far and I cant seem to get it to work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can i see your route code in web.php

Comment: What is `this.form.show`? Is it from a package (if so which one) or is it something you've created (if so please can you show the code for it)?

Answer (score 0):

try [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding), that's much more better

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a slash on after `'api/loadData'`.It could be

```
loadStudentData(id) {
    this.form.show('api/loadData/' + id).then(({data}) => (this.studentsData = data));
}
```

However, you did not publish your routes here.